# Apache CXF Logging

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I have some problems with my server-client communication via web services with `Apache CXF framework`. I want to log the server errors to an external file instead of terminal. Piece of code for server;

```
server= new JaxwsNotificationBroker("Hello",..);
server.setAddress("http://localhost:" + brokerPort + "/wsn/NotificationBroker");
```

And I tried this for logging;

```
server.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
server.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

But it gives the error `The method getInInterceptors() is undefined for the type JaxwsNotificationBroker`.

Is there any method to log the errors for `JaxwsNotificationBroker`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can add `loggingInInterceptor` & `logOutInterceptor` inside `cxf:bus`

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:ininterceptors>
      <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
    </cxf:ininterceptors>
    <cxf:outinterceptors>
      <ref bean="logOutInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outinterceptors>
  </cxf:bus>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your spring config file, if you are using spring:

```
    <cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging />
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

don't forget to add cxf namespace as

```
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use log4j for logging you must put a META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger file onto the classpath with the 'org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger' class name in it as a single line, otherwise cxf will use the JavaTM 2 platform's core logging facilities.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, gnodet wanted to keep all the WS-N stuff as independent from CXF as possible and only rely on pure JAX-WS stuff.  Thus, nice methods for things like the CXF interceptors aren't possible.  :-(

Looking at the code, the only option right now would be to write a subclass of JaxwsEndpointManager that would call the super.register method, then cast it to the CXF EndpointImpl, and set the interceptors on there.  Not really ideal.  :-(